# Fastest way to get mysql result into BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have a mysql table of 104M rows. Using the method of [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), it takes almost three hours and costs $5.

What would be the fastest way to query or copy a mysql table and get it into BQ? For example, is there a way to stream the mysql database (which is not on GCP) directly into a csv file on GCS and then load the csv file from BQ? We've noticed [loading csv files from GCS into BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) is quite fast.

What would be the suggested way to get the data from an external mysql table (or any external database, really) into BQ in the fastest way possible?

---

**Update**: Note that we're not trying to reduce our data size by doing an incremental feed (which we already do). This question is just asking what's the absolute fastest way to get 100M rows of data (let's say 15GB) into BQ from an external database.

Comment: I've never done it, but I'd imagine the fastest way would be to export the table as CSV, and upload it to GCS. You could also use Cloud Dataflow, and write a custom sink to talk to MySQL, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @GrahamPolley any benchmarks on how/why this would be faster than a straight streaming insert?

Comment: No. Streaming will be faster, but you have to pay for streaming inserts remember. You'll also need to bake into exponential back-off-and-retry with streaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a series of blogpost were WePay shows their way of accomplishing this:

- https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/bigquery-wepay

> The MySQL to GCS operator executes a SELECT query against a MySQL
>   table. The SELECT pulls all data greater than (or equal to) the last
>   high watermark. The high watermark is either the primary key of the
>   table (if the table is append-only), or a modification timestamp
>   column (if the table receives updates). Again, the SELECT statement
>   also goes back a bit in time (or rows) to catch potentially dropped
>   rows from the last query (due to the issues mentioned above).

With Airflow they manage to keep BigQuery synchronized to their MySQL database every 15 minutes.

---

Addendum (as the question wants to know the fastest way to insert rows into BigQuery):

- Streaming inserts is the quickest way to get data into BigQuery, but there is a limit of 100,000 rows per second. 100M rows will take 100 seconds at least at this rate.
- `bq load` a file in GCS (json, csv, avro) is usually the quickest way to import data in bulk and for free.
- Try a federated query: Put your (json, csv, avro) files in GCS, and instead of running a traditional import - query data straight from GCS. This should be faster than `bq load` (no need to wait for the load scheduler), and you can output the results of a `SELECT *` to a new BQ native table. The cost of this will be the cost of the query (scanned bytes).

Comment: Hey Felipe, thanks for this answer. We're already doing full vs. incremental refresh already so the above isn't quite what we're looking to find out. Basically, if we have 1M rows in a mysql database, what is the **fastest** way to import that data into BQ? (not how to reduce the size of the query itself -- take that as a given.)

Comment: oh, I see  - I added some thoughts

Comment: > Streaming inserts is the quickest way to get data into BigQuery

@FelipeHoffa - are you saying that streaming is faster than loading from GCS?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa thanks for the update -- any way to benchmark a 1M transfer to BQ? That is, for 1M rows from a non-GCP database, how the three above perform in time?

Comment: @David542 the best benchmark is your own benchmark! Any blockers to proceed?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa after benchmarking this we found that saving to csv and loading csv file was MUCH faster than the streaming insert -- about 8.5x faster in our use case. We were only ever able to achieve ~10K/sec operations in streaming operations (regardless of the amount of threads we used, etc.) -- we do have lots of string fields so maybe this has to do with the slower throughput.

Comment: Cool! Did you try the federating querying? (put file in GCS, create a BigQuery table pointing to that file, SELECT * -> save results to table)